# How can I reshape a series so that I can use it the Scitkit-learn Standard Scaler function?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

For the below code, I get a **ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array** error message.

So instead of the last line in the below, I also tried `scaler.fit_transform(df[0]).reshape(-1,1)` but got the same error.  How can I transform a pandas series so I can scale it using the scikit learn StandardScaler?

```
In [1]: import numpy as np
    ...: import pandas as pd
    ...: from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
    ...: from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    ...: X = np.random.uniform(size=15)
    ...: index = pd.date_range(start = "2020-12-31", periods=15)
    ...: df = pd.DataFrame(X, index=index)

In [2]: scaler.fit_transform(df[0])
```

Comment: You should use `scaler.fit_transform(df[0].values.reshape(-1, 1))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not apply the reshape function to the dataframe but to the output of `StandardScaler`.

What you need to do is apply the reshape function to the dataframe values

```py
df_r = df[0].values.reshape(-1, 1)
```

to get a 2d vector and then pass this to `StandardScaler`

```py
scaler.fit_transform(df_r)
```

Alternatively, you can do this in one step like in Flavia Giammarino's comment.

Comment: Suppose X = np.random.uniform(size=(15,2)) instead of X = np.random.uniform(size=15).  Why do I not have to reshape `scaler.fit_transform(df)` but I do have to reshape `scaler.fit_transform(df[0].values.reshape(-1, 1))` In other words, why do 2D arrays and greater  not need to be reshaped but 1D arrays do need to be reshaped?

Comment: `fit_transform()` only accepts array-like objects of shape `(n_samples, n_features)`, denoting to 2d arrays (see the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.fit_transform)). It is simply an API specification which must be adhered to. The output of `np.random.uniform(size=15)` is a 1d array and violates this rule. Specifying `size=(15, 2)` above however produces a 2d array why it does not need any further reshaping.

Comment: And btw, 3d arrays and above need to be reshaped as well. It **must** be 2d.